# Interop Toolkit - "Out of memory" message

Tags: wpf, vb.net, vb6

I was wondering if anybody encountered this problem or no the solution. The VB6 form that consumes our vb.net interop usercontrol throws an "Out of Memory" message when our WPF usercontrol under vb.net uses an external resources xaml (color, fonts and so on). We don't get any error when usercontrol.resources are all inside the usercontrol xaml. Of course we would like to keep those resources outside of individual xamls for re-usability.

If anybody have experience with this, can you please give a suggestion?

Thank you.

Comment: Is this really `VB6` with `WPF`?

Comment: Well, it's more of WPF user control hosted inside vb.net user control, provided by the interop toolkit, that's hosted inside Vb6 winform.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer though by going through going and trying a bunch of different things. VB6 is very picky when it comes to WPF and Vb.NET. "Out of memory" is the message it throws every time something is off in either of the controls. In this case, as soon as I put my resource files under the root directory, where my WPF control is, it worked. Same thing happened when I started adding properties to vb.net control file. One has to tread carefully around Interop.